# Corner Radius for a Label on UItableviewCell is not applying in xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uilabel, xcode8

Here is my code

```
[cell.label.layer setCornerRadius:cell.label.frame.size.width/2];
```

here is what I tried :-

```
cell.label.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

also tried :-

```
cell.label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

also I have Imported:-

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

none of these approaches works.

Also I have tried it in both IOS 9 and IOS 10 and in Simulator as well as device,
anyone there who is facing the same Issue?

**Answer**

Well After some trial and error Methods I found that passing absolute value to the corner radius parameter worked.

```
[cell.label.layer setCornerRadius:20.0];
```

which comes to the last question how can you set corner radius for label dynamically when using Storyboard for tableview.

Comment: Well After some trial and error Methods I found that passing absolute value to the corner radius parameter worked.
[cell.label.layer setCornerRadius:20.0];

Comment: Where did you put the `[cell.label.layer setCornerRadius:cell.label.frame.size.width/2];` code?

Comment: @Mr.UB this code will be in uitableview's cellForRowAtIndexpath: Method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting this

```
cell.label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

in `awakeFromNib` or `init` if you are not using xib or storyboard and put

```
cell.label.layer.cornerRadius = cell.label.frame.size.width/2;
```

in `layoutSubviews` of your `UITableViewCell`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks that sure helps. but how to dynamically do when using storyboard.

Comment: This code will work with setting it dynamically. Since the view is loaded with different frame then to match the screen size from the storyboard and then when the system actually layout all the views it gives the actual frame to match the screen size the best place to put these type of frame depended code in a UIView subclass is layoutSubviews